# Is there a difference between foo.try(&:to_s?) and foo.try(:to_s?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I thought `try` is always with `symbol` like `foo.try(:to_s?)`.
But I found `foo.try(&:to_s?)` also works and I couldn't find difference between them.

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: I added a tag `ruby-on-rails` since there is no such thing as `try` method in pure ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.try(&:to_s?)` is shorthand for

1. Calling `to_proc` on `:to_s?`, this will give you something that's kinda like this: `->(thing) { thing.public_send(:to_s?) }`
2. Taking that Proc and make it into a block
3. Passing it as a block parameter to `try`

So the whole thing becomes something similar to this:

```
foo.try { |f| f.public_send(:to_s) }
```

and when `try` receives a block parameter, it simply yields to that block if the receiver is something other than `nil`, so it becomes further equivalent to this:

```
foo.to_s
```

which in effect nullifies the guarding effect of `try` in this particular case.

On the other hand, `foo.try(:to_s)`, passes the symbol `:to_s` as an argument to the `try`.

So `foo.try(:to_s?)` isn't really equivalent to `foo.try(&:to_s?)`.

See for example:

```
"hey".try(:foo)
# => nil
"hey".try(&:foo)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for "hey":String
```

Comment: The conclusion is correct, but the reasoning is wrong. 1. `foo.try(&:to_s?)` is not shorthand for `foo.try(:to_s?.to_proc)`, which is not equivalent to `foo.try { |f| f.public_send(:to_s) }`.

Comment: 2. Showing `try(&:to_s?)` to be equivalent to `try {|f| f.public_send(:to_s)}` doesn't lead to `try(:foo)` not being equivalent to `try(&:foo)`. Generally, `x == y` does not lead to `z != x`. You have a complete logical flaw.

Comment: I corrected my explanation of `&:to_s?`. I'm sure the OP caught the drift despite of the purported logical fallacy. Perhaps next time you'll indulge us with an answer of your own, @sawa.

Comment: I think it is now correct regarding `foo.try(&:to_s?)`. But your explanation "`foo.try(:to_s)`, passes the symbol `:to_s` as an argument to the `try`". Is a tautology. It is not explaining anything. Perhaps you can expand on that.